# Create a PEM from a PPK file

Tags: ssh, putty, openssh, pem

So there are plenty of tutorials on how to convert a `PEM` to a `PPK` using `puttyGen`. However my issue is that my windows machine had the only `PEM` copy and I converted it into a `PPK` and deleted it. Now I need to figure out how to convert a `PPK` into a `PEM` so that my mac can `ssh` into the server. I still have access to the server so I could also just make a new key if I had to, anyone know how to convert `PPK` to `PEM`?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

1. Install *PuttyTools*

   ```
   apt-get install putty-tools
   ```
2. Generate a `pem` file form the `ppk`

   ```
   puttygen server.ppk -O private-openssh -o server.pem
   ```

The file *server.pem* file will be saved on same location

Comment: Since the OP mentioned using the .pem key on a Mac, I'll just mention that you can run the same `puttygen` command on the Mac after installing the `putty` package using Homebrew.

Comment: on centos / redhat : 'yum install putty' provides the relevant executable

Comment: works like a charm @Emizen !

Comment: In case anyone's wondering if that -0 is a zero, don't. It's an "O".

Comment: "-O" is unrecognized as a command in Windows -  different command required for Windows?  Suggestion:  Open PuTTYgen
Click ‘Load’ and select your .ppk file
Once the key is loaded, go to ‘Conversions’ in the menu and select ‘Export OpenSSH key’
Save your new .pem file

Answer (score 12):

If you're on a Mac and you've previously installed [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), from Terminal:

```
$ brew install putty
$ puttygen server.ppk -O private-openssh -o server.pem
```

The first command was suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273180/create-a-pem-from-a-ppk-file#comment72377609_38854929) and the second from [Emizen Tech's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38854929/173497).

Answer (score 2):

Try this to install putty-tools

```
sudo apt install putty-tools
puttygen key.ppk -O private-openssh -o key.pem
ssh -i ~/key.pem {user}@{ip}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, install PuTTY for Mac using

```
brew install putty
```

Then, use the following command to convert the .ppk format private key to a standard PEM format private key:

```
puttygen privatekey.ppk -O private-openssh -o privatekey.pem
```

Make sure permissions on the private key file are set properly. It should only be readable by the user that owns it.

```
chmod go-rw privatekey.pem
```

You can now use the key for logins from scripts and command line with:

```
ssh -i privatekey.pem user@hostname
```

Comment: On the final `ssh` I get Enter passphrase for key - I enter the login password and I get Invalid key length.