# Getting permission errors while transferring datasets to an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to transfer files present on Kaggle, to an EC2 instance. Accoring to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261190/how-to-get-kaggle-competition-data-via-command-line-on-virtual-machine), the command to be used from Putty is

> "scp -i /path/my-key-pair.pem /path/cookies.txt user-name@ec2-xxx-xx-xxx-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~".

However, I am getting the following error:

> [ec2-user@ip-172-31-32-16 ~]$ scp -i /path/my-key-pair.pem /path/cookies.txt ec2-34-214-179-99.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:~ Warning: Identity file /path/my-key-pair.pem not accessible: No such file or directory. The authenticity of host 'ec2-34-214-179-99.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (172.31.32.16)' can't be established. ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:PdEvoAAd7Bc37PbnODNkNiqy/zE2MwoVzCv8jw8McfI. ECDSA key fingerprint is MD5:66:c2:b4:7e:50:a2:a8:67:ec:84:2c:ee:76:02:74:b0. Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-34-214-179-99.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com,172.31.32.16' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts. Permission denied (publickey). lost connection

Apparently This occurs when the key does not have the right permissions. One suggestion I received is to search for chmod 400 equivalent for windows. I did but did not find anything appropriate. Please help

Comment: *Warning: Identity file /path/my-key-pair.pem not accessible: No such file or directory*

Comment: I have a .ppk file. And I have mentioned the paths correctly

Comment: Convert your ppk file to a pem file.  The two formats can contain generally the same data, but they are not interchangeable. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38854929/1695906